# How to display vendor image file in cakephp .ctp file

Tags: cakephp, components, captcha, vendor

i have created component secureimage captcha and now i want to display **"vendor files audio/refresh.png"** file which is placed under vendor/secureimage/images/refresh.png  and vendor/secureimage/images/audio_icon.png

code -----------

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/adminpanel_login/captcha/securimage_play.swf?bgcol=#ffffff&amp;icon_file=/adminpanel_login/captcha/audio_icon.png&amp;audio_file=<?php echo $captcha_hear;?>" height="32" width="32">
     <param name="movie" value="/adminpanel_login/captcha/securimage_play.swf?bgcol=#ffffff&amp;icon_file=/adminpanel_login/captcha/audio_icon.png&amp;audio_file=<?php echo $captcha_hear;?>" />
</object> 

<a tabindex="-1" style="border-style: none;" href="#" title="Refresh Image" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src ='<?php echo $this->webroot;?>admins/securimage/' + Math.random(); this.blur(); return false"><img src="<?php //echo $captcha_image_refresh;?>/adminpanel_login/captcha/refresh.png" alt="Reload Image" height="32" width="32" onclick="this.blur()" align="bottom" border="0" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put images in the webroot, that way they can be served directly by your webserver and not by php.

You can do this by symlinking the image from `vendors` to `webroot/img`

Comment: i already did that ..i am searching way to use vendors files in .ctp directly.